# using angularjs how can i get thumbnails of pdf and video?

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

I want to make thumbnails of pdf,images and video file using angularjs
I found one git example for that

[`https://github.com/aztech-digital/angular-thumbnails`](https://github.com/aztech-digital/angular-thumbnails)

Please go through the link i have tried this but i am new in angularjs and I dont know how to call a directive.

Please help me to implement this i am using php codeigniter with angularjs

what I want is I have an option to upload multiple files which will contain pdf,doc,docx,xls,mpg,jpg etc.I want to create a thumbnail of all these type of files. for eg: if a case I am uploading pdf the first page of pdf should be the thumbnail of that file.

how i can implement this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/0GiS0/Yvgc2/)

here i saw one example which will create only for images

Thank you

Comment: You can get the base64 string from backend and show in html like this `<img ng-src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{{image}}"/>`. Here image is a base64 string.

Comment: i haven't understand what you are telling can you please explain it

Comment: Can you create a base64(jpeg) string for pdf or video and return that on a service? I don't know how to do it in php but you can search for it.